# Issue with XML Source

Tags: xml, ssis-2012

I am trying to load data from XML file to SQL Server table Using SSIS package,
but it keeps on getting me this error while executing it and XML source in Data flow.

If I execute it in different PC with same XML file, I get any error messages but with company PC I do.

```
Error Message,
**Error 1**"The XML Source was unable to process the XML data. Object 
reference not set to an instance of an object."
**Error 2:**[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  
The PrimeOutput method on XML Source returned error code 0xC02092AF.  The 
component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called 
PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, 
but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be 
error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6Lrj.png) is XML file used:

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your xmlsource file does not contain valid xml that's why this error occured.
Use below xml data.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <counters>
      <counter>
         <extractDate>2007-12-O5</extractDate>
         <category>dispatcher</category>
         <name>server1</name>
         <runtime>6</runtime>
         <queue>3</queue>
         <maxrequest>8</maxrequest>
         <color>blue</color>
         <hostName>svo2555</hostName>
         <path>\\dispatcher</path>
         <lastaccessed>2007-O2-03</lastaccessed>
     </counter>
     <counter>
         <extractDate>2007-12-O5</extractDate>
         <category>gateway</category>
         <name>server1</name>
         <runtime>1</runtime>
         <queue>10</queue>
         <maxrequest>10</maxrequest>
         <color>purpIe</color>
         <hostName>svo2555</hostName>
         <path>\\gateway</path>
         <lastaccessed>2007-02-03</lastaccessed>
     </counter>
 </counters>
```